# How to write joins in orm

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Test(models.Model):
   name =  models.CharField(max_length=50)

class TestDetails(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   test = models.ForeignKey(Test,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   mark = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I create a TestDetails when a user signs up for a test. I need to get the list of tests that the user has **not** signed up.

Comment: Try `Test.objects.exclude(testdetails__user=my_user)`

Comment: @Selcuk Doesn't that assume a `related_name` that doesn't appear to be set on `TestDetails.test`? I think the default would be `test_details_set` in this case.

Comment: @kungphu No, `_set` convention generates a convenience property to access all child objects. In a query you should be using the actual model name. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/ for more examples; for example `Reporter.objects.filter(article__headline__startswith='This')`. Note that it is `article__headline` and not `article__set__headline`.

Comment: Well that's interesting. I can't say I like the fact that it uses `testdetails` instead of `test_details`; seems a little counter to the way names are usually treated in Python and Django.

Comment: @kungphu Agreed, it is a bit inconsistent but I guess the reason was to reduce the number of underscores in a long traversal, or it's just `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.